# Why can't a Java Thread object be restarted?

Tags: java, multithreading

I know that it is not possible to restart a used Java Thread object, but I don't find an explanation *why* this is not allowed; even if it is guaranteed that the thread has finished (see example code below).

I don't see why `start()` (or at least a `restart()`) method should not be able to somehow reset the internal states - whatever they are - of a Thread object to the same values they have when the Thread object is freshly created.

Example code:

```
class ThreadExample {

  public static void main(String[] args){

    Thread myThread = new Thread(){
      public void run() {
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
          try{ sleep(100); }catch(InterruptedException ie){}
          System.out.print(i+", ");
        }
        System.out.println("done.");
      }
    };

    myThread.start();

    try{ Thread.sleep(500); }catch(InterruptedException ie){}
    System.out.println("Now myThread.run() should be done.");

    myThread.start(); // <-- causes java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException

  } // main

} // class
```

Comment: my multi-threading skills aren't too advanced, but from the little I know there is no (real) guarantee that your thread will be done in 500ms. It could end up having low priority and waiting, or even worse in a lock in some more advanced case. That being said, I also think it's an interesting question why a thread with state, `TERMINATED` can't be restarted.

Comment: @posdef: The example code is just to demonstrate the problem. One could use a more elaborate mechanism that waits till `myThread.run()` has finished for sure (or accept that in rare cases an exception is thrown).

Comment: I'm not aware of any systems in which you *can* restart a thread.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> I know that it is not possible to
>   restart a used Java Thread object, but
>   I don't find an explanation why this
>   is not allowed; even if it is
>   guaranteed that the thread has
>   finished (see example code below).

My guestimation is that Threads might be directly tied (for efficiency or other constrains) to actual *native* resources that might be re-startable in some operating systems, but not in others. If the designers of the Java language had allowed Threads to be re-started, they might limit the number of operating systems on which the JVM can run.

Come to think of it, I cannot think of a OS that allows a thread or process to be restarted once it is finished or terminated. When a process completes, it dies. You want another one, you restart it. You never resurrect it.

Beyond the issues of efficiency and limitations imposed by the underlying OS, there is the issue of analysis and reasoning. You can reason about concurrency when things are either immutable or have a discrete, finite life-time. Just like state machines, they have to have a terminal state. Is it started, waiting, finished? Things like that cannot be easily reasoned about if you allow Threads to resurrect.

You also have to consider the implications of resurrecting a thread. Recreate its stack, its state, is is safe to resurrect? Can you resurrect a thread that ended abnormally? Etc.

Too hairy, too complex. All that for insignificant gains. Better to keep Threads as non-resurrectable resources.

Answer (score 15):

I'd pose the question the other way round - why *should* a Thread object be restartable?

It's arguably much easier to reason about (and probably implement) a Thread that simply executes its given task exactly once and is then permanently finished.  To restart threads would require a more complex view on what state a program was in at a given time.

So unless you can come up with a specific reason why restarting a given `Thread` is a better option than just creating a new one with the same `Runnable`, I'd posit that the design decision is for the better.

(This is broadly similar to an argument about mutable vs `final` variables - I find the final "variables" much easier to reason about and would much rather create multiple new constant variables rather than reuse existing ones.)

Comment: One reason for the desire of `restart` is the cost of creating new (and garbage collecting old) Thread objects.

Comment: Then just use a thread pool where each thread can be reused across multiple Runnables.

Comment: as Steve says, use a thread pool mechanism. I love the ease of use of the ExecutorService implementations that can be obtained through the static methods of the Executors class. Use runnables as your restartable tasks.

Comment: @Curd - have you profiled your application and found that the cost of object allocation and thread GC makes up a non-negligible runtime cost?  Unless you're doing something *insane*, it almost certainly won't.  And in this case, just send `Runnable`s to a thread pool (such as `ThreadPoolExecutor`).

Answer (score 2):

Because they didn't design it that way.  From a clarity standpoint, that makes sense to me.  A Thread represents a thread of execution, not a task.  When that thread of execution has completed, it has done its work and it just muddies things were it to start at the top again.

A Runnable on the other hand represents a task, and can be submitted to many Threads as many times as you like.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you want to create a new Thread?  If you're concerned about the overhead of creating your MyThread object, make it a Runnable and run it with a `new Thread(myThread).start();`

Comment: That still incurs **on the same thread creation overhead** once the runnable's run() method comes to an end (or ends abruptly.) The way to avoid such overhead is by creating thread pools or custom thread classes that wait till they get *messaged* with a `Runnable` (or some other command-like object) to run. Once it ends, the enclosing Thread goes to sleep until it gets/receives another one. Or a pool of consumer custom Threads consuming `Runnable` objects placed in a queue.

Comment: This still requires the creation of new (and garbage collection of old) Thread objects.

Comment: @luis.espinal: Good point. Why don't you write this as an answer?

Comment: @Curd: No, not the way luis.espinal describes it. The actual thread (i.e. the instance `java.lang.Thread`) never terminates, it justs waits when it's done, until it receives a new `Runnable`. Only the `Runnable`s get created and GCed, and these can be as lightweight as you want/need.

Answer (score 1):

Java Threads follow a lifecycle based on the State Diagram below.  Once the thread is in a final state, it is over.  That is simply the design.
[image]

Comment: That's clear, but what are the reasons it was designed that way?

Answer (score 0):

You can kind of get around this, either by using a `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor`, or manually by having a thread that calls `Runnable.run()` on each `Runnable` that it is given, not actually exiting when it is finished.

It's not exactly what you were asking about, but if you are worried about thread construction time then it can help solve that problem. Here's some example code for the manual method:

```
public class ReusableThread extends Thread {
    private Queue<Runnable> runnables = new LinkedList<Runnable>();
    private boolean running;

    public void run() {
        running = true;
        while (running) {
            Runnable r;
            try {
                synchronized (runnables) {
                    while (runnables.isEmpty()) runnables.wait();
                    r = runnables.poll();
                }
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                // Ignore it
            }

            if (r != null) {
                r.run();
            }
        }
    }

    public void stopProcessing() {
        running = false;
        synchronized (runnables) {
            runnables.notify();
        }
    }

    public void addTask(Runnable r) {
        synchronized (runnables) {
            runnables.add(r);
            runnables.notify();
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, this is just an example. It would need to have better error-handling code, and perhaps more tuning available.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned with the overhead of creating a new Thread object then you can use executors.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
public class Testes {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executor.execute(new Testes.A());
        executor.execute(new Testes.A());
        executor.execute(new Testes.A());
    }   
    public static class A implements Runnable{      
        public void run(){          
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId());
        }
    }
}
```

Running this you will see that the same thread is used for all Runnable objects.

Answer (score 0):

A `Thread` is not a *thread*.  A *thread* is an execution of your code.  A `Thread` is an object that your program uses to create and, manage the life-cycle of, a *thread*.

Suppose you like playing tennis.  Suppose you and your friend play a really awesome set.  How would your friend react if you said, "That was incredible, let's play it again."  Your friend might think you were nuts.  It doesn't make sense even to talk about playing the same set again.  If you play again you're playing a *different* set.

A *thread* is an execution of your code.  It doesn't make sense to even talk about "re-using" a thread of execution for same reason that it makes no sense to talk about re-playing the same set in tennis.  Even if another execution of your code executes all the same statements in the same order, it's still a *different* execution.

Andrzej Doyle's asked, "Why would you *want* to re-use a `Thread`?"  Why indeed?  If a `Thread` object represents a thread of execution---an ephemeral thing that you can't even talk about re-using---then why would you want or expect the `Thread` *object* to be re-useable?

Answer (score -1):

i've been searching the same solution which you seem to be looking for, and i resolved it in this way. if you occur mousePressed Event you can terminate it also reuse it, but it need to be initialized, as you can see below.

```
class MouseHandler extends MouseAdapter{
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {            
        if(th.isAlive()){
            th.interrupt();
            th = new Thread();
        }
        else{
            th.start();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is actually creating a new thread not resetting the old thread object.